# Connect with openssl to server with DHE-RSA ciphersuite

Tags: openssl

I want to try connect with openssl to tlslite-ng server with any DHE-RSA (for example TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256), but everytime I get

```
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 347 bytes
```

I tried some -cert ca.cert etc., but then I get `unable to load client certificate private key file`.

Can someone help me, how to correctly generate certificates etc. and how to use openssl, to be able to connect with DHE-RSA?

Comment: Are you certain you can create your own certificate? Or do you need the site to issue one to you? For information on creating a certificate, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Comment: That 2nd site is what I wanted about creating certificate, thanks, but still dont know how to use it in openssl. Can you please give me example, how to use it? If i got something like "openssl -connect localhost:4433 -cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256", but what about other parameters (-cert, -CAfile), which and how I must use them?

Comment: The other question is kind of big. You should ask it as a separate question. Likely, you should break it into subtasks, and then ask a question when you have a problem with a part of the subtask. If its a question on how to use commands, then you should ask it at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.